# how to not return negative values when hit decrement value at 0

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to implement value which doesn't allow user to pass negative value as this button functioning to print pages.

```
class _QuantityCounterState extends State<QuantityCounter> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void increment() {  
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  void decrement() {  
    setState(() {
      _counter--;
    });
  }
```

Comment: use a conditional statement i-e   if(_counter !=0){_counter--}

Comment: Try my solution. It is more elegant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void decrement() {  
    setState(() {
      _counter=<0 ? _counter=0 : _counter--;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

More elegant solution:

```
import 'dart:math';
 

    void decrement() {  
        setState(() {
          _counter = max(_counter-1, 0);
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an extension like this:

```
extension MakePositive on int {
  int toPositive() {
    return this < 0 ? 0 : this;
  }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
void decrement() {  
    setState(() {
      _counter = (_counter-1).toPositive();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
void decrement() {
  setState(() {
    if (_counter > 0 && _counter != 1) {
      // will stop at 1
      _counter--;
    }

    if (_counter >= 1) {
      // will stop at 0
      _counter--;
    }
  });
}
```